# How to match everything before the first occurrence of a 3 to 18 digit number using Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write out a code in Python that would match a pattern of text and be saved in a list.

Below are the example 3 lines from a text file:

```
FY20 Jan 8 Special Buy Event    592586642 - Dummy text Dummy text 
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text - 592586642, Dummy text Dummy text

FY20 Last Minute Gifts (Next Day/PUT)   "364706825 - dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text - 364706825 dummy text

FY20 Early Access   484015830 dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text - 484015830 dummy text
```

Below is the regex that I used:

```py
with open('test.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    promo = []
    item = []
    for line in f:
        #yo = re.findall('(FY20[\s\w]+)\t([0-9]+)', line)
        yo = re.findall('(FY20[^\d+]*)+([0-9]*)', line)
        try:
            promo.append(yo[0][0])
            item.append(yo[0][1])
        except:
            continue
```

The above code matches everything before occurrence of a number. It works fine for the last 2 lines and saves the proper results--promo type and item number in the list. However, for the first line, it only matches the number "8" and gives out an empty list for **item**

```py
item = ['', '364706825','484015830']
promo = ['FY20 Jan\t', 'FY20 Jan 8 Special Buy Event\t','FY20 Last Minute Gifts (Next Day/PUT)\t', 'FY20 Early Access\t']
```

I want the regex to match everything before a certain range of digits occur.

```py
item = ['592586642', '364706825','484015830']
promo = ['FY20 Jan 8\t', 'FY20 Jan 8 Special Buy Event\t','FY20 Last Minute Gifts (Next Day/PUT)\t', 'FY20 Early Access\t']
```

**Do not worry about cleaning the results, I just need the proper results for now**

I have tried using `(FY20[^\d+]*)+([0-9]*)` and `(FY20[^\\d{3,18}]*)+([0-9]*)` and many others but did not find a way to get through everything. Do I have to use a conditional `if-else` statements to match this pattern?

Comment: If you write things like `[^\d+]` there's something you have misunderstood about character classes. Read about them and about quantifiers (greedy and non-greedy).

Comment: I don't know why but this `'FY20 Jan 8 Special Buy Event\t'` should be impossible to captured with this: `(FY20[^\d+]*)+` I tried you code and it extracted `8` not an empty string?

Comment: Why doesn't `item` have four numbers? Should it be `['592586642', '592586642', '364706825', '484015830']`??

Answer (score 2):

You can try to practice regex patterns with your examples on [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com),
[Regular Expression `(?P<promo>.*?)(?P<item>\d{3,18}).*`](https://www.debuggex.com/i/CQALyv1TJLCy-EBy.png) .

Try groups pattern, example, with `groupdict()`:

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CQALyv1TJLCy-EBy)

**Code**:

```
with open('test.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
text = f.read()
promo = []
item = []
p = re.compile('(?P<promo>.*?)(?P<item>\d{3,18}).*')
for t in text.split('\n'):
    res = p.search(t)
    if res is not None:
        res_dict = res.groupdict()
        promo.append(res_dict['promo'])
        item.append(res_dict['item'])
print (promo)
print (item)
```

Use `\d{2}\d+` - for 3 or more digits or `\d{3,18}` - for 3 to 18 digits if you want and read about python [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). `groups()` `groupdict()` is not mandatory but simpler maintain long **regex**.

Comment: To format the code, select it and type `ctrl-k`. [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Can you show separating the digits into the `item` list and the *text* in the `promo` list like the OP wants? You went to the trouble of making named groups - might want to use `groupdict()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex :

**Regex :**

```
FY20(.*?)(\d{3,18})
```

**Demo :** [Here](https://regex101.com/r/FpDkEh/2)

**Python Sample :**

```
import re


text = '''
FY20 Jan 8 Special Buy Event 592586642 - Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text - 592586642, Dummy text Dummy text

FY20 Last Minute Gifts (Next Day/PUT) "364706825 - dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text - 364706825 dummy text

FY20 Early Access 484015830 dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text - 484015830 dummy text
'''

res = re.findall(r'FY20(.*?)(\d{3,18})',text)
print(res)
```

**Demo :** [Here](https://repl.it/repls/BuoyantTomatoDemoware)

**Output :**

```
[(' Jan 8 Special Buy Event ', '592586642'), (' Last Minute Gifts (Next Day/PUT) "', '364706825'), (' Early Access ', '484015830')]
```

**PS : To include `FY20` use this regex `(FY20.*?)\d{3,18}`**

Comment: `d{9}` - OP wants that to match a string of digits three to eighteen characters in length.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works well for now. Will surely reach out if any complications occur

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> text = '''
... FY20 Jan 8 Special Buy Event 592586642 - Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text - 592586642, Dummy text Dummy text
... FY20 Last Minute Gifts (Next Day/PUT) "364706825 - dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text - 364706825 dummy text
... FY20 Early Access 484015830 dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text - 484015830 dummy text
... '''
>>> text = [t for t in text.split('\n') if len(t) > 10]
>>> text
['FY20 Jan 8 Special Buy Event 592586642 - Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text - 592586642, Dummy text Dummy text', 'FY20 Last Minute Gifts (Next Day/PUT) "364706825 - dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text - 364706825 dummy text', 'FY20 Early Access 484015830 dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text - 484015830 dummy text']
>>> for t in text :
...     re.findall( r'\d{3,18}', t )
... 
['592586642', '592586642']
['364706825', '364706825']
['484015830', '484015830']
>>> for t in text :
...     pattern = re.findall( r'\d{3,18}', t )
...     print t[:t.find(pattern[0])]
... 
FY20 Jan 8 Special Buy Event 
FY20 Last Minute Gifts (Next Day/PUT) "
FY20 Early Access 
>>>
```

I use `re` to find the number you need, then just a simple string manipulation to find this pattern and print out the result.